# Can $\{x\}$ be empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $(A,B)\in R\iff(\exists x\in\Bbb R)(B=A\cup\{x\})$

I have a bunch of properties I'm supposed to (dis)prove for the said relation $R$. I think it's impossible for $\{x\}$ to be an empty set but i wanted to double check.

Comment: $x\in\{x\}$, so it is not empty. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You seem to be defining $R$ in terms of $R$. Or is one of those meant to be the set of reals?

Comment: By definition $\{x\}$ is not empty: $x$ is a member of it.

Comment: @halrankard2 
(A,B)∈R where R is a relation
x∈R, R is set of real numbers

Comment: I have edited your question based on what I though you likely wanted to convey. Please revert if you intended the question to be different. And welcome to the site! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations in future.

Comment: @TitoEliatron when it comes to natural numbers, 0 can be defined as {} so i wanted to check if I was missing some weird way of defining an empty set. (the ZF set theory)

Comment: If $x=\{\}$ then $\{x\}=\{\{\}\},$ which is not the empty set: it is a non-empty set whose only element is the empty set.  So even with “weird” numbers a non-empty set is still non-empty.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you very much for showing me that! I get confused when working with ZF